# What's wrong with my Extended Euclidean Algorithm (python)?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

My algorithm to find the HCF of two numbers, with displayed justification in the form `r = a*aqr + b*bqr`, is only partially working, even though I'm pretty sure that I have entered all the correct formulae - basically, it can and will find the HCF, but I am also trying to provide a demonstration of Bezout's Lemma, so I need to display the aforementioned displayed justification. The program:

```
# twonumbers.py
inp = 0
a = 0
b = 0
mul = 0
s = 1
r = 1
q = 0
res = 0
aqc = 1
bqc = 0
aqd = 0
bqd = 1
aqr = 0
bqr = 0
res = 0
temp = 0
fin_hcf = 0
fin_lcd = 0
seq = []
inp = input('Please enter the first number, "a":\n')
a = inp
inp = input('Please enter the second number, "b":\n')
b = inp
mul = a * b # Will come in handy later!
if a < b:
    print 'As you have entered the first number as smaller than the second, the program will swap a and b before proceeding.'
    temp = a
    a = b
    b = temp
else:
    print 'As the inputted value a is larger than or equal to b, the program has not swapped the values a and b.'
print 'Thank you. The program will now compute the HCF and simultaneously demonstrate Bezout\'s Lemma.'
print `a`+' = ('+`aqc`+' x '+`a`+') + ('+`bqc`+' x '+`b`+').'
print `b`+' = ('+`aqd`+' x '+`a`+') + ('+`bqd`+' x '+`b`+').'
seq.append(a)
seq.append(b)
c = a
d = b
while r != 0:
    if s != 1:
        c = seq[s-1]
        d = seq[s]
    res = divmod(c,d)
    q = res[0]
    r = res[1]
    aqr = aqc - (q * aqd)#These two lines are the main part of the justification
    bqr = bqc - (q * aqd)#-/
    print `r`+' = ('+`aqr`+' x '+`a`+') + ('+`bqr`+' x '+`b`+').'
    aqd = aqr
    bqd = bqr
    aqc = aqd
    bqc = bqd
    s = s + 1
    seq.append(r)
fin_hcf = seq[-2] # Finally, the HCF.
fin_lcd = mul / fin_hcf
print 'Using Euclid\'s Algorithm, we have now found the HCF of '+`a`+' and '+`b`+': it is '+`fin_hcf`+'.'
print 'We can now also find the LCD (LCM) of '+`a`+' and '+`b`+' using the following method:'
print `a`+' x '+`b`+' = '+`mul`+';'
print `mul`+' / '+`fin_hcf`+' (the HCF) = '+`fin_lcd`+'.'
print 'So, to conclude, the HCF of '+`a`+' and '+`b`+' is '+`fin_hcf`+' and the LCD (LCM) of '+`a`+' and '+`b`+' is '+`fin_lcd`+'.'
```

I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me to find out what is going wrong with this.

Comment: Just a readability suggestion: you can do `inp = a = b = ... = 0` for all values that are initialized to the same number.

Comment: Side note: in Python you can swap variables like `a,b = b,a`.

Comment: Side note #3: don't use `+` to build large strings (and definitely don't use backticks instead of `repr`!). `"Using Euclid's Algorithm, we have now found the HCF of {1} and {2}: it is {3}".format(a, b, fin_hcf)` is a lot nicer to look at.

Answer (score 9):

Hmm, your program is rather verbose and hence hard to read.  For example, you don't need to initialise lots of those variables in the first few lines.  And there is no need to assign to the `inp` variable and then copy that into `a` and then `b`.  And you don't use the `seq` list or the `s` variable at all.

Anyway that's not the problem.  There are two bugs.  I think that if you had compared the printed intermediate answers to a hand-worked example you should have found the problems.

The first problem is that you have a typo in the second line here:

```
aqr = aqc - (q * aqd)#These two lines are the main part of the justification
bqr = bqc - (q * aqd)#-/
```

in the second line, `aqd` should be `bqd`

The second problem is that in this bit of code

```
aqd = aqr
bqd = bqr
aqc = aqd
bqc = bqd
```

you make `aqd` be `aqr` and then `aqc` be `aqd`.  So `aqc` and `aqd` end up the same.  Whereas you actually want the assignments in the other order:

```
aqc = aqd
bqc = bqd
aqd = aqr
bqd = bqr
```

Then the code works.  But I would prefer to see it written more like this which is I think a lot clearer.  I have left out the prints but I'm sure you can add them back:

```
a = input('Please enter the first number, "a":\n')
b = input('Please enter the second number, "b":\n')
if a < b:
    a,b = b,a

r1,r2 = a,b
s1,s2 = 1,0
t1,t2 = 0,1
while r2 > 0:
    q,r = divmod(r1,r2)
    r1,r2 = r2,r
    s1,s2 = s2,s1 - q * s2
    t1,t2 = t2,t1 - q * t2

print r1,s1,t1
```

Finally, it might be worth looking at a recursive version which expresses the structure of the solution even more clearly, I think.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple version of Bezout's identity; given *a* and *b*, it returns *x*, *y*, and *g* = gcd(*a*, *b*):

```
function bezout(a, b)
    if b == 0
        return 1, 0, a
    else
        q, r := divide(a, b)
        x, y, g := bezout(b, r)
        return y, x - q * y, g
```

The `divide` function returns both the quotient and remainder.

Answer (score 0):

The python program that does what you want (please note that extended Euclid algorithm gives only one pair of Bezout coefficients) might be:

```
import sys

def egcd(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return (b, 0, 1)
    g, y, x = egcd(b % a, a)
    return (g, x - (b // a) * y, y)

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        's program caluclates LCF, LCM and Bezout identity of two integers
        usage %s a b''' % (sys.argv[0], sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)

    a = int(sys.argv[1])
    b = int(sys.argv[2])

    g, x, y = egcd(a, b)

    print 'HCF =',  g
    print 'LCM =', a*b/g
    print 'Bezout identity:  %i * (%i) + %i * (%i)  = %i' % (a, x, b, y, g)

main()
```